# X over SSH causes Xorg crash

Tags: ssh, xorg, steam

'ello. So, I've a rather interesting issue. This is more of an OpenSSH issue, or so I'm led to believe. Both of these systems are running Ubuntu (one has libraries present but no Xorg instance, the client viewer has KDE installed). I'm also using Ubuntu 14.04.

I'm trying to use X11 Fowarding over SSH to forward a Steam client (yes, that Steam) from another system on my local network. Unfortunately, it appears that after a specific point in time, Xorg will crash (and then promptly respawn) on the machine that is trying to view the Steam client.

It appears the point of crashing is when the Steam UI itself has to load. I'm able to accept the EULA and it will sometimes manage patching the client initially, but when presented with a login screen that I would use to log into Steam with, I'm instead greeted with a black screen while Xorg tries to revive itself.

The only error message or log I have relating to this is:

```
steamwebhelper[8975]: segfault at 0 ip 00000000f26dec19 sp 00000000ffe0df20 error 4 in libcef.so[f2241000+501b000]
```

Does anyone have any potential solutions? I'm kind of stuck honestly. I'd really like to get this working.

Comment: Does this happen with any other programs or just steam? Did you download steam from the package manager or from the steam website?

Comment: @EatMyTacoCrumbs It's just Steam. I've managed this with both Skype and Teamspeak3. I manually downloaded the package from the Steam website and dpkg'd it, then apt-get install -f to get it's dependencies (what might've been missed).